# how to ignore Self Signed Certificates with the HttpClient in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, httpclient

```
    private async void GetDataAsync()
    {        
        var test_uri = "my-uri";
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, error) => true;//worked on uwp

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
        //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, ssl) => true;
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(test_uri);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
           
            Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(content);
            //Debug.WriteLine(Single.Parse(root.Items[0].Value.ToString()));
            for (int i = 0; i < root.Items.Count-1; i++)//
            {
                ChartEntriesForLineChart.Add(
                    new ChartEntry(Convert.ToSingle(root.Items[i].Value))
                    {
                        Color=SkiaSharp.SKColor.Parse("#2c3e50"),
                        Label=root.Items[i].Timestamp.ToString(),
                        ValueLabel=root.Items[i].Value.ToString()
                    });
            }
        }
        this.LineChart.Entries = ChartEntriesForLineChart;
        
    }
```

This code can be executed normally（ignore the ssl self -certificate,Complete basic certification and get the json data from server） in the uwp project of xamarin.forms, but when I deployed it to the Android emulator to run, I encountered the following exception：

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'System.Net.Security.Native assembly: type: member:(null)'

[image: image of the exception]

What is the correct way to complete basic authentication by ignoring SSL in xamarin.forms? Including uwp, Android, apple, I have tried many methods？

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

#### in iOS

The problem is that a self-sign cert is considered insecure and non-trusted by iOS, thus you have to apply an ATS exception to your app so iOS knows that your app is untrusted in the **Info.plist**.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>xxx.com</key> // your domain here
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

#### in Android

Use **[Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction)** to implement it

in forms , create the Interface

```
public interface IServerCommunication
{
    Task<string> GetFromServerAsync(string URL);
}
```

in Android project

```
public async Task<string> GetFromServerAsync(string URL)
{
    HttpClient client = PreparedClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    try
    {
        response = await client.GetAsync(URL);
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return "error";
    }
}

private HttpClient PreparedClient()
{
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

    //not sure about this one, but I think it should work to allow all certificates:
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chaun, ssPolicyError) =>
    {
        return true;
    };


    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

    return client;
}
```

invoke it before create the HttpClient .

```
string result = await DependencyService.Get<IServerCommunication>().GetFromServerAsync(URL);
```

Comment: Which platform did you test ?

Comment: pixel 3a Pie 9.0-api 28,and android 10.0 -api29,I try to replace httpclienthandler with androidclienthandler and the error I get is"java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException:'Trust anchor for certificaiton path not found'"。

Comment: @Every, I experience the same. I'm not sure of alternatives, but per this Xamarin issues discussion, I gather that the method is specific to the HttpClientHandler - https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3682